# Replace query result with case/when failing

Tags: case

Using MS SQL, I like to replace the information in the OEM_Description column when the column Item translation (IT).Description is NULL and when the language setting of the customer C.[Language Code] is English (ENG) into the original item description (I.[Description])

I have come up to this query:

```
SELECT
    "OEM_Description" = 
CASE 
   WHEN  (C.[Language Code] = 'ENG' and IT.[Description] = NULL)
   THEN I.[Description]
  ELSE IT.[Description]
END,
C.Name as Customer_Name
```

However the information is only being replaced if I test on "C.[Language Code] = 'ENG'" as soon as i add the test for IT.[Description] = NULL nothing is replaced anymore.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention what DBMS, but you probably need `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`. However,  you're creating a complex case when this is a texbook use of [`COALESCE ()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE):

```
SELECT
    "OEM_Description" = COALESCE( IT.[Description], I.[Description] ),
    C.Name as Customer_Name
```

Alternate solution based on comment:

[IS NULL is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null) but a replacement for `= NULL` in your original like this:

```
SELECT
    "OEM_Description" = 
CASE 
   WHEN  (C.[Language Code] = 'ENG' and IT.[Description] IS NULL)
   THEN I.[Description]
  ELSE IT.[Description]
END,
C.Name as Customer_Name
```

Comment: Hi Chris, your last change was the solution, I copied the = NULL example from some website, but did not now that this was not the same as IS NULL. Its now working as expected. Thanks!